# Upgrade Asus Zenfone 4 Z01KD to > 8 OS

Tags: updates, 9.0-pie, operating-system, asus-zenfone-2

As of September 2022, Slack will stop supporting the app for Android OS versions earlier than 9 (Pie). I have an Asus Zenfone 4 Z01KD mobile, stuck at Android 8. I have read suspicious guides online on how to download software updates of dubious origin to flash the upgrade "manually", or on how to get developer options activated and make the ZUI update recognize there is an actual update of the OS available. The latter don't work for me and the former look messy or dangerous.

Is it possible to safely upgrade a Zenfone 4 to OS later than 8? (There is no tag for #zenfone4, but only for #zenfone3 and #zenfone5).

Comment: Assuming that [Z01KD is ZE554KL](https://www.gizmochina.com/product/asus-zenfone-4-2017/), perhaps as you know, [there doesn't seem any official update to non-beta Android 9](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/01/06/asus-abandons-plans-to-update-zenfone-4-to-android-9-pie/). This leaves the only option: custom ROM. However, searching a little bit about custom ROM for this specific model... doesn't seem promising at all.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. Why do you say not promising ? (which by the way, is my same impression). Would you mind posting the least worst solution, just to have an available option to compare with?

Comment: Because I couldn't find any custom ROM for this specific model at all, even on XDA Forum (which is supposed to be the main hub for ROM developers). Either their community had a technical difficulty in developing one, or there's no interest in making one. Thus, my current answer as of now would be: there's no way to upgrade past Android 8, unless using an incomplete beta Android 9 is okay.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks. What about Android 10 or 11?